# $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{sin}\:X>\frac{1}{2})$ if $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$

Tags: probability, trigonometry, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. Find $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{sin}\:X>\frac{1}{2})$.

Tried a few times to integrate this, but can't get to the final result.

Comment: Find the set of points $x > 0$ such that $\sin(x) > 1/2$. (It will be the union of infinitely many intervals.) Then integrate over this set by taking the integral over each interval and summing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First find $\{x \ge 0: \sin(x) > 1/2\}$.  This is the union of a sequence of intervals.  Find the probability of each, and then sum a geometric  series.